# How it is possible to 'rotate image, only if it is in portrait mode (But not in landScape mode)'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In my **iphone** application *I have used image view to display the enlarged images, getting from another view*,

in **first view** i have a specified place for *display ing images captured from imagePicker*,
*`Here images are displayed in correct orientation what we captured`*

In the **(2nd) detail view**, *i have a large (3x4) image view to display the captured image in bigSize*, *`(Here ALSO images are displayed in correct orientation what we captured)`*

**But**

My requirement is i need to display large image in 3x4 pixel ratio image view,

For this

**If image in landScape mode display it in as it is orientation,**

**If it is in portrait mode we need to rotate it to landscape (90˚).**

How it is possible to **`rotate image , ONLY IF it is in portrait mode (But not in landScape mode)`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to check the size of the image in terms of height and width. If the height of the image is greater than the width of the image clicked then this means that you have taken the image in portrait mode.